# Relationship between standard half-normal and standard normal distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

Let X be a standard half-normal random variable with pdf:

$$f(x) = \cfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{{-x^2}/{2}}$$

and let Z be a random variable such that P(Z = X) = 1/2 and P(Z = -X) = 1/2.

How to show that Z is a standard normal variable?

I tried the following:

$$P(Z<a) = P(Z<a|Z=X).P(Z=X) + P(Z<a|Z=-X).P(Z=-X)$$
$$\implies P(Z<a) = \cfrac{1}{2} [P(X<a) + P(X>-a)]$$

and then got stuck. Any pointers?

Comment: Crossposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3596964/321264. Please decide where you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment:* Notice that for standard normal $X,$ you have $P(X < 1.5) + P(X > -1.5),$ etc.

In R: 'pnorm', with mean 0 and variance 1 by default, is the standard normal CDF. Then you have, for one value of $a:$

```
pnorm(1.5)
[1] 0.9331928
1 - pnorm(-1.5)
[1] 0.9331928
```

[image]